# Undefined method where for Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a straightforward question. I run into this error

`NoMethodError: undefined method where for #<Class:0x00000004eef3c8>`

when I try to execute this ActiveRecord query

```
accounts = Account.where("created_at > #{Date.today.prev_year}").limit(10)
```

I don't understand why this is. I am trying to get an array of 10 items with a created_at time stamp from the previous year's date.

The [API activerecord docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) illustrate the example and my syntax seems correct. Also, the ruby on rails guides gives this example as well `Client.where("orders_count = '2'")`. I don't understand whhy I'm unable to perform the query. Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: What's `Account` look like?

Comment: Could you add your Account class code?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the speedy comments. I'm using Rails 2.3. and @DaveNewton and Mariekou, was there something you're looking for in particular for the Account model? I ask because the Account model code is 733 lines long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ".where" and ".limit" syntax isn't in rails 2.3.  Also, the conditions are wrong - Date.today.prev_year will give the string version of a time, like `"2013-09-30 16:35:36 +0100"`.  You need to compare it against the database time string format which is different.  It's best to let rails handle the conversion.

Try this:

```
accounts = Account.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 1.year.ago.to_date], :limit => 10)
```

EDIT:  btw, you can convert a time/date into the relevant database format with

```
mytime.to_s(:db)
```

Remember, in the database this is effectively string comparison, so if you wanted to put it into a where string you'd need to wrap it in quotes.

```
accounts = Account.find(:all, :conditions => {"created_at > '#{1.year.ago.to_date.to_s(:db)}'"}, :limit => 10)
```

or

```
accounts = Account.find(:all, :conditions => {"created_at > #{1.year.ago.to_date.to_s(:db),inspect}"}, :limit => 10)
```

Comment: This did the trick! I'll have to be more careful and check what version of Rails I'm using. Thanks.